# rJava no running JVM found error- .jinit() also not working

Tags: r, rjava

I have installed rJava on my laptop with 64 bit windows 7 OS. When I try to run this sample thingy from the rJava documentation, it gives the following error:

```
library(rJava)

Double <- J("java.lang.Double")

Error in .jcall("java/lang/Class", "Ljava/lang/Class;", "forName", cl,  : 
  No running JVM detected. Maybe .jinit() would help.
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(class)) : 
  No running JVM detected. Maybe .jinit() would help.
```

As suggested by the error message above, I tried .jinit() but that thing takes forever to load.

I also checked if my Java was 64 bit using cmd, and it says I have 64 bit Java.

```
C:\Users\516221>java -version

java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

What might be the reason? I have the jvm.dll file into my classpath as well.

I also have the JDK installed.

```
C:\Users\516221>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_25
```

Comment: You might need the JDK (Java Development Kit) its used for the runtime stuff like this.

Comment: I have JDK installed already!

Comment: run javac -version and post back what it says.

Comment: I did as you said and it says:

javac -version

javac 1.8.0_25

Comment: What more needs to be checked?

Comment: Check this:go on ninite.com check the java jdk 32 bit or 64 bit and download it.Run the ninite exe and let ous now if it works.

Comment: I have the jdk installed and it is 64 bit as well, I checked by the command java -d64 -version.